# How can I rename the device files for my multi-memory card reader?

Tags: usb, udev, devices, block-device, sd-card

I have a card reader in my computer that can read six different types of memory cards. It's connected to an internal USB port, and it shows up in `lsusb` as "Bus 002 Device 013: ID 058f:6364 Alcor Micro Corp. AU6477 Card Reader Controller". This thing has slots for SD, microSD, Memory Stick, M2, XD, and CompactFlash. This appears to the computer as four drives, one for SD/microSD, one for Memory Stick/M2, one for XD, and one for CompactFlash.

Now here's my problem. It appears as `/dev/sdd`, `/dev/sde`, `/dev/sdf`, and `/dev/sdg`. I'd like to change these to more meaningful names, and save the `sd?` names for actual hard drives. You know, just to make it more clean. This is especially annoying (well, at least as annoying as something in `/dev` can really be) because out of all those slots, I really only use the SD and microSD ones, which are both `/dev/sdd`, so I don't even *use* `e`, `f`, and `g`. (I'm pretty sure I've only used a non-SD slot once, to get photos off my aunt's CompactFlash digital camera.)

My laptop's SD card reader shows up as `/dev/mmcblk0`. How can I tell udev to use this name for the SD card reader, and give a similarly-meaningful name to the other ones?